# PDO retorna apenas um regristro

Tags: php, slim, slimframework

Olá.

Meu algoritmo está retornando apenas um registro do banco de dados. Já revisei o código várias vezes, mas não consigo entender o motivo.
Estou usando o Slim Framework.

Segue o código:

index.php

```
$app->get('/ticket', function(Request $req, Response $res){
$tickets = new Ticket($this->db);
$tickets = $tickets->getTickets();

$res->getBody()->write("Todos os tickets: ");
var_dump($tickets);

$this->logger->addInfo('Busca todos os tickets');

return $res;
```

});

Ticket.php

```
require "ConDb.php";

class Ticket extends ConDb

{
private $DB;

function __construct($db)
{
    parent::__construct($db);
}

function getTickets()
{
    return $this->read();
}

function getTicketById($id)
{
    return $this->read($id);
}
```

}

ConDb.php

```
abstract class ConDb

{
private $DB;

function __construct($db)
{
    $this->DB = $db;
}

function read($id = null)
{
    try{
        if($id != null)
        {
            $stmt = $this->DB->prepare("SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE id = ?");
            $stmt->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        }
        else
        {
            $stmt = $this->DB->prepare("SELECT * FROM tickets");
        }

        if($stmt->execute())
        {
            return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new PDOException("Nao foi possivel realizar a operacao.");
        }
    } 
    catch(PDOException $erro)
    {
        echo "Erro: ".$erro->getMessage();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Perceba que no arquivo ConDb.php  você utiliza $stmt->fetch, para retornar mais de um registro, usa-se fetchAll()

Comment: Obrigado Everton! Era isso mesmo. É que eu estou começando a aprender agora. Valeu!

Answer (score 2):

O metodo `fetch` do PDO vai retornar o proximo registros ( ou seja, apenas uma linha ). O metodo `fetchAll` vai retornar todas as linhas da sua consulta.

fetch : https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetch.php
fetchAll: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: Obrigado Matheus! É isso mesmo. Abraço.